c++ cmake in main.cpp was not declared in this scope(solved)
problem:
in a cmake project, I included header file in the main.cpp successfully, but when I tried to use the implemented class, it had compile error:
\cpp_projects\folder_test\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
\cpp_projects\folder_test\main.cpp:6:5: error: 'firstImpl' was not declared in this scope

I tried to adjust cmakelists.txt, google this situation, and even asked chatgpt, but no useful way could be applied.
could anyone help and tell me what I missed in cmakelists.txt?
Or, did I use the interface in a wrong way?
Why it seemed like no link between the interface and its implmentation?
the cmake project structure and every file content as below:
project_root/
│
├── interface/
│   ├── first.h
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│
├── implement/
│   ├── firstImpl.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│
├── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt

first.h
class Ifirst {

  virtual void test() = 0;
};

CMakeLists.txt
add_library(Ifirst INTERFACE)
target_sources(Ifirst first.h)

firstImpl.cpp
#include "interface/first.h"
#include <iostream>

class firstImpl final : public Ifirst {
private:
public:
  void test() override {
    std::cout << "hi, i am in test function\n";
  }
};

CMakeLists.txt
add_library(firstImpl firstImpl.cpp)
target_link_libraries(firstImpl INTERFACE Ifirst)

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "interface/first.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, from test_folder!\n";
    firstImpl op;
    //Ifirst if_v = &op;

    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(test_folder VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_library(compiler_flags INTERFACE)
target_compile_features(compiler_flags INTERFACE cxx_std_20)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()


add_executable(test_folder main.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_folder PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/interface)

target_link_libraries(test_folder PUBLIC firstImpl INTERFACE Ifirst)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)


after adjustment
project_root/
│
├── interface/
│   ├── first.h
|   ├── firstImpl.h
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│
├── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt

first.h
class Ifirst {
private:
public:
  virtual void test() = 0;
};

firstImpl.h
#include "first.h"
#include <iostream>

class firstImpl final : public Ifirst {
private:
public:
  void test() override {
    std::cout << "hi, i am in test function\n";
  }
};

CMakeLists.txt
add_library(first_h INTERFACE first.h)
#target_include_directories(first_h INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
#target_sources(first_h INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/first.h)

add_library(firstImpl_h INTERFACE firstImpl.h)
#target_include_directories(firstImpl_h INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
#target_sources(firstImpl_h INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/firstImpl.h)

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "interface/firstImpl.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, from test_folder!\n";
    firstImpl op;

    //Ifirst& if_v = op;
    //if_v.test();
    Ifirst* if_v = &op;
    if_v->test();

    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(test_folder VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_library(compiler_flags INTERFACE)
target_compile_features(compiler_flags INTERFACE cxx_std_20)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(interface)

add_executable(test_folder main.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_folder PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/interface)

target_link_libraries(test_folder INTERFACE firstImpl)


The compiler is correct. You need to move the definition of the firstImpl class to a header file, and include that file where you need to use the class. Otherwise there's no way for the compiler to know about it.

This is also a very good time to learn about the concept of translation unit. This is the basic unit that the compiler actually works on, and anything not in a translation unit will be unknown. In short, a translation unit is a single source file with all included header files.

Since firstImpl is declared in firstImpl.cpp it cannot be used in main.cpp. If you want classes, variables, functions etc to be used in multiple files you should declare them in a header file. That's what header files are for.

Perhaps you want to keep firstImpl hidden and only use the interface Ifirst. If that's the case you need to add a function to first.h to create an Ifirst derived object like firstImpl.

You could leave it hidden but then use a factory pattern however you still can't mention firstImpl in int main() instead you use some type of pointer to an Ifirst object that the factory pattern returns.

thanks guys, I think I misunderstand the relationship of interface(pure virtual class), implementation class of the interface(only class declaration and method override declaration), and actual content of method implemented in another .cpp file.

And for simplification, I think I should just use two header files. One for interface(pure virtual class), and another for implementation class of the interface(class declaration and method override with actual content)
